# Linux Core Dump Without Killing Process

Tags: linux, memory, dump, memory-dump

Is it possible to generate a core dump without killing the process?  If so, what is the command/signal to do so?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 13):

See the 'gcore' command, part of GDB.

Comment: This looks promising.  I got core file this way.  However, the process I'm analyzing terminates as soon as I detach gdb from it.  It also terminates immediately if I strace it.

Do you know any way to prevent it from detecting that it's getting attached by gdb/strace?

Thanks again!

Comment: You can run gcore against the process and then gdb against the dumped core. Like: "gcore 12345; gdb /path/to/binary core.12345"

Answer (score 3):

I had the best success with attaching gdb in batch mode to the running program, get a backtrace and then detach.

```
gdb --batch --quiet -ex "set pagination off" -ex "thread apply all bt"
-ex "detach" -ex "quit" pid pid_of_process
```

Comment: but backtrace is not a coredump

Comment: You may obtain the backtrace from a coredump.

Answer (score 0):

A method to generate a coredump directly from program without `gdb` is described here:
   https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11185/dump-process-core-without-killing-the-process

It make sense only if you are developing. Principle is to fork program and to raise `SIGABRT` from child.